# How to replace a property name in an claim? Change the Property name of a value?

Tags: wikidata

There are a number of cases where a I would like to change the property name used in a claim from one to another. Basically from [P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P279) "Instance of" to [P279](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) "Subclass of", for an existing statement. This involves recreating all the parameters.

Looking for something faster to just replace the property selected and not have to enter in all the parameters.

Example is [Q622666](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q622666) "Siege tower", it was an instance of a siege engine, but it is not an instance, it is a subclass.

```
Removed claim: instance of (P31): siege engine (Q655697)
Created claim: subclass of (P279): siege engine (Q655697)
```